# How do I make a web app/apiapp in azure private?

Tags: api, azure, web-applications, private

I've done this before but the feature seems to have disappeared. I want to host an API in azure but set it to private so that only other azure entities in my subscription can see it.

It used to be achieved with a "private" switch on the webapp/apiapp settings.

Comment: you can use virtual network with network security group. For more information, see [this article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-app-service-environment-control-inbound-traffic/).

Comment: Thanks for your response Jack.  I'm hoping there is a cheaper and simpler solution.  it used to be so easy.

Comment: you can do ip filtering by using this setting in web.config <system.webServer>   
  <security> 
    <ipSecurity allowUnlisted="false" denyAction="NotFound"> 
      <add allowed="true" ipAddress="192.168.1.0" subnetMask="255.255.255.0"/> 
    </ipSecurity> 
  </security>    
</system.webServer>  you block all ip addresses by default and then add the ones you want to allow.

Comment: Thanks Aravind.  This work around is good for small projects however at the enterprise level it would create a maintenance overhead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Responding to clean up my unanswered questions.

Turns out you can't just define a webapp/apiapp as private anymore and the way to do it now is to wrap it in a private virtual network. As suggested by Jack Zeng (https://stackoverflow.com/users/5760649/jack-zeng) in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create it in an ASE (App Service Environments) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/environment/intro

It is more expensive than the normal one, but it has a better performance.